# how to write pyramid handlers

Tags: python-2.7, pyramid

Here's the code that declares adress for application

```
def includeme(config):
    a = config.add_handler  
    a('fileupload', '{lang}/case/fileupload{sep:/*}{name:.*}', ImageUpload)
```

And here class ImageUpload

```
@action(route_name='fileupload')
class ImageUpload():

    def __init__(self,request):

    @action(request_method='GET', renderer="json")
    def get(self):        

    @action(request_method='POST', xhr=True, accept="application/json", renderer='json')
    def post(self):
```

And when I try to go to the ru/case/fileupload/ it get me nothing, what's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your actions, currently they are named 'get' and 'post'. You probably want to use `@action(name='index', ...)` on your methods, and then `config.add_handler(..., action=index')`.

Comment: No I wanted that handler choose a method in spite of request_method='GET'

Comment: I can't parse what problem you have with my solution. It's the same as yours except.. simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Only decidion that i found it looks like

```
def includeme(config):
   a = config.add_handler
   a('modeluploadget', '/fileupload{sep:/*}{name:.*}', ModelUpload, request_method='GET', action='get')
   a('modeluploadpost', '/fileupload{sep:/*}{name:.*}', ModelUpload, request_method='POST', action='post') 
   a('modeluploaddelete', '/fileupload{sep:/*}{name:.*}', ModelUpload, request_method='DELETE', action='delete')
```